# Guardar archivo en PATH especificado en el parámetro del método .create()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

1.- Tengo creado los siguientes modelos creados, en total son màs de 31 modelos; sin embargo
la idea es reducir todos los modelos a uno solo.

```
class ArchivosGrupo7734(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7734',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7734')
    estacion =models.CharField(max_length=300)
    familia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)

class ArchivosGrupo7777(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7777',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7777')
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)

class ArchivosGrupo7746(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7746',max_length=30)
    ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7746')
    estacion =models.CharField(max_length=300)
    familia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    feature = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

2.-Si el grupo es por ejemplo 7734 que se guarde el archivo en la ruta o PATH especificado en ruta= 'Archivos/Grupo/7734/%s' ,
item representa el nombre completo del archivo con su extensiòn.

De la forma siguiente, ya hace la inserciòn a la BDD, pero no crea el PATH o directorio, de igual forma aunque el PATH ya exista
,el archivo no llega a esa ruta o no se refleja en la ruta.

```
if grupo='7734'

    ArchivosHospitality7734.objects.create(

                                    ruta='Archivos/Grupo/7734/%s' %(item),
                                    estacion=lineaPdf,
                                    familia=familiaPdf,
                                    feature=feature,

                                    usuario=usuarioSesion

                                    )

if grupo=='7777':
    ""

if grupo=='7746':
    ""
```

3.- La unica forma de que llegen los archivos al Path es no usar el mètodo .create(); sin embargo esta forma no es muy practica
ya que es necesario tener una tabla por cada grupo por el hecho de ordenar los archivos en cada una de sus carpetas.
Es decir:

```
/*Carpetas*/

            Archivos/Grupo/7734
            ""
            ""
            Archivos/Grupo/7777
            ""
            Archivos/Grupo/7746


            /*No usando el método .create()*/

            datos=ArchivosGrupo7734()

                        datos.ruta=item
                        datos.estacion = lineaPdf
                        datos.familia = familiaPdf
                        datos.feature = featurePdf
                        datos.usuario=usuarioSesion


                        Mensaje='Subido'
                        datos.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Una sugerencia para que puedas agrupar: crea un modelo que contenga los atributos comunes a cada grupo, es decir, fecha, proyecto, ruta, etc... para luego cuando crees grupos especificos, estos hereden del general todos los atributos comunes ejemplo:

> `class Archivo(models.Model):
>       fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
>       estacion =models.CharField(max_length=300)
>       familia = models.CharField(max_length=300)
>       feature = models.CharField(max_length=300)
>       usuario=models.ForeignKey(User)`
>
> Luego creas entonces los grupos especificos con atributos especificos:
>
> `class Grupo7777(Archivo):
>       proyecto=models.CharField(default='Proyecto 7777',max_length=30)
>       ruta = models.FileField(upload_to='Archivos/Grupo/7777')`
>   
>   Creo que asi te quedaria mas organizado